# How Can I Stop The Brush From Painting Black as Soon as I Add a Texture?

Tags: texturing, texture-painting, color

When I'm painting (in 3.6), the colour works fine until I add the texture, then the colour changes to black no matter what I pick. If I disable the texture, it goes back to painting in my selected colour, but then I can't use the texture.

I couldn't find anything on google except for [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/133334/why-is-blender-2-8-messing-up-my-colors-in-texture-paint-image-editor) and [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/75662/texture-paints-brush-is-always-black), and those solutions didn't work for me.

[image: Texture Paint Settings]

I also tried enabling and disabling a whole bunch of random options, and it didn't change anything.

[image: Texture Settings]

Comment: Note: it only happens with custom image textures, if I use the built in ones like clouds, it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, I was using a png image for my brush, which Blender doesn't like for some reason.
Instead I had to change the brush image to white, and put it on a black background, then it started working fine with colours.